# How can I parse different structures with Boost.Spirit.Qi?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-fusion

In [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/employee.cpp), employee structs are parsed in the form "employee{int, string, string, double}".

I would like to know whether it is possible to modify this example to also parse different types of structs, like "intern{int, string, string}".

Specifically, I would like to then pass the structure to a function overloaded on the structure type. It would be great if I can avoid using polymorphic double dispatch for this, and instead preserve the concrete type that gets parsed to statically match the correct overloaded function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's possible. Create a rule for each of the types you want to parse:

```
rule<Iterator, std::string()> s = ...;
rule<Iterator, intern()> intern_r = int_ >> s >> s;
rule<Iterator, employee()> employee_r = int_ >> s >> s >> double_;
```

and combine those into an alternative:

```
rule<Iterator> r = 
        intern_r   [phoenix::bind(receive_intern, _1)]
    |   employee_r [phoenix::bind(receive_employee, _1)]
    ;
```

This assumes you have 2 functions handling the parsed data:

```
void receive_intern(intern const&);
void receive_employee(employee const&);
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this would work perfectly, although the compile times will probably be quite high with many different structures. Is there anything I could do to split them off into different compilation units?